# ImportError: No module named PyMySQL

Tags: python

I have installed python 3 using this command

```
sudo apt-get install python3-minimal
```

after that I have downloaded python extension in vs code. 
I want to connect it to mySql database but as I write

```
import PyMySQL
```

It shows this stack trace

> Unable to import 'PyMySQL'pylint(import-error)

Comment: did you run `pip3 install pymysql`?

Comment: yes I did this already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also install `python3-pymysql`

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pymysql
```

And your import should be lowercase:

```
import pymysql
```

**EDIT:** Make sure that you have started the same python interpreter from the same installation (check version displayed in python prompt when starting)

Comment: same as stated in  my post

Comment: What version of python are you running? You installed `pymysql` for version 3. Did you start python by running python3?

Comment: I am usignn 3.6.7

Comment: How are you starting the interpreter? Can you confirm that you get the import error when python3 interpreter is running?

Comment: How to start it?

Comment: On your terminal, run `python3`. Then run `import pymysql` and see if you get the import error.

Comment: I run my script using start debugging option in visual studio code

Comment: Run the command `Python: Select Interpreter` (Control-Shift-P) and choose the python interpreter for the version for which you installed pymysql.

Comment: Have you configured your mysql instance? This should be out of the scope of pymysql. You need to configure your mysql server installation on your machine.